# Unable to call second activity from asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I need to call a new activity from onPostExecute() method of ASyncTask but the context is returning null.

```
public class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<String>> {


public final String search = "https://www.google.co.in/search?&tbm=isch&q=";
public final String searchAlbum = "album+art";
ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> urlList=new ArrayList<String>();
Context context;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {
    System.out.println(urls.length);

    arrayList.clear();
    urlList.clear();

    for(int i=0;i<urls.length;i++) {
        String url = urls[i];
        String finalUrl = search + url + searchAlbum;

        try {
            //Log.i("URL", finalUrl);
            urlList.add(finalUrl);

            Document document = Jsoup.connect(finalUrl).get();

            String result = document.toString();

            //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<img class=\"rg_ic rg_i\" data-src=\"(.*?)\" data-sz");

            Pattern newPattern = Pattern.compile("\"ou\":\"(.*?)\",\"ow\"");

            //Matcher m = pattern.matcher(result);

            Matcher newMatcher = newPattern.matcher(result);

            if(newMatcher.find())
                arrayList.add(newMatcher.group(1));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Printing Images");
    System.out.println(urlList);
    System.out.println(arrayList);

    return arrayList;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    if(context!=null) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context,MusicPlayerActivity.class).putExtra("arrayImages",arrayList);
    context.startActivity(i);}
    else
        Log.i("Context","NULL"); //Check why it is null*****
    super.onPostExecute(strings);
  }
}
```

The Output is Context:NULL.

Why is it null, i have tried making a variable of type MainActivity and Activity, but both doesn't solve the problem.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You never set `context` so yes, it is null.

Comment: What should i do to use it in intent.

Comment: A non-null `context` like an Activity. Perhaps you can pass the calling Activity (that is hosting the AsyncTask) to it?

Comment: @KenWolf Thx... I made a constructor with the parameter as context and passed the context of the calling activity into the  constructor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your `context` variable but never set it:

```
Context context;
```

So yes, it is `null` when you try and use it.

You should populate it before you try to use it - perhaps pass a reference to to the calling `Activity` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Put this ImageDownloadTask  inside your Activity, then you can call it using below code

```
 new MyTask().execute(urls);
```

and on you ImageDownloadTask change onPostExecute function to this one

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
            super.onPostExecute(strings);
            Intent i = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, MusicPlayerActivity.class).putExtra("arrayImages", strings);
            startActivity(i);


        }
```

}
}